# Insertar imagenes en MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, imagen, blob

Estoy creando una base de datos tipo tienda con MySQL, concrtamente PHPmyadmin y me interesaría añadir un campo tipo BLOB para incluir imágenes de los productos manualmente desde LOCAL, sin ningún tipo de formulario para que el user incluya la foto, sino incluir yo las fotos directamente en la BD. Al crear este campo, me da la opción de incluir las imágenes pero a la hora de mostrar toda la información me da un error en el campo de imagen y me muestra sólo letras y símbolos. Este es el código HTML/PHP que tengo de momento.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
   
    $cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tienda");
?>
    
    <table class="table table-striped">
          
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                <th>CATEGORIA</th>
                <th>PRECIO</th>
                <th>IMG</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
    <?php foreach ($cxn->query('SELECT * from productos') as $row){ 
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['tipo'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['titulo'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['descripcion'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['genero'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<img src = "data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['img']) ." width = '50px' height = '50px'/>"?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de mostrar este tipo de datos?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué error da? ¿Seguro que esa imagen es de tipo `.png`? Por lo general es mejor guardar las imágenes en archivos y en la BD guardar sólo la ruta/nombre.extensión. Si no tienes otra opción que guardarla en BLOB te aconsejo que guardes el tipo al momento de insertar, porque como haya más de un tipo de imagen te será muy complicado adivinarlo a la hora de mostrarla.

Comment: Nunca es buena idea meter imágenes dentro de la BD. Guárdalas en un almacenamiento local o remoto y en la BD solo pones las rutas de la imágenes.

Comment: Te falta cerrar la comilla doble del src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenes que usar base64_encode

```
<? $firma = base64_encode($row->firma); ?>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=$firma?>"/>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos